# Fullcalendar: Delete event on button click in dayGrid view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am trying to delete events on button click using:

```
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
            element.append( "<span class='closeon'>X</span>" );
            element.find(".closeon").click(function() {
               $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',event._id);
            });
        },
```

but it deletes all events in the calendar instead of clicked event. I've tried other solutions provided but they are either with list item view or dayagenda view (timeGrid in v4) while I am using month view (dayGrid) only. My js of fullcalendar is as follows:

```
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('fullcalendar/packages/core/main.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('fullcalendar/packages/interaction/main.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('fullcalendar/packages/daygrid/main.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('moment/moment.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('js/jQuery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'bootstrap' ],
        themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
         header: {
        left: false,
        center: 'title',
        },
        defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
        validRange: {
          start: '2019-08-26',
          end: '2019-09-26',
        },   
        selectable: true,
        editable  : true,
        droppable : true,
        eventSources: [
          {
            url: '{{"roster/getEvents"}}',
            allDay: false,
            allDayMaintainDuration: false,
            textColor: 'black',

          },
          {
            url: '{{"roster/getGazette"}}',
            editable: false,
            overlap: false,
          },
        ],
      });

    calendar.render();
    });
    </script>
```

Note: I've also tried using dialog like this:

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

            id= calEvent.id;

            $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                  resizable: false,
                  height:100,
                  width:500,
                  modal: true,
                  title: 'Want you want to do?',
                  buttons: {
                             CLOSE: function() {
                                 $("#dialog").dialog( "close" );
                             },
                             "DELETE": function() {
                                //do the ajax request?
                             }
                           }
             });
       },
```

but it gives "typeerror $(...).dialog is not a function" upon click.

Comment: Could you create a simple fiddle with your example?

Comment: I am using fullcalendar in laravel so i dont know if it is possible to create fiddle for it.

Comment: Look http://jsfiddle.net/tpde8Luw/1/ button deletes only chosen event

Comment: @Mat.Now I added the code but creates the same problem with "Failure parsing JSON 
Object { message: "Failure parsing JSON", xhr: XMLHttpRequest }"  and stops all events to render.

Comment: @RazaZaidi that sounds like a separate issue with an AJAX request somewhere in your code. It's not clear, from what you've shown, where that might be

Comment: @RazaZaidi P.S. Which version of fullCalendar are you using? Half the code you've shown is related to v3 and half to v4. They are not really compatible. It would help us to help you if you clarify that.

Comment: @ADyson its 4.3. I am editing the code to show full js.

Comment: Ok well firstly you should make sure you only use code samples and documentation relating to version 4, otherwise you will get stuck all the time. Version 3 is very different and most code for it will not work in version 4 without changes.

Comment: `$(...).dialog is not a function` will probably be because you didn't include that jQuery plugin in your page. It's not part of the basic jQuery package. I'm guessing you're trying to use this: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/ ? if so then you need to make sure you added jQueryUI to your page.

Comment: @ADyson Noted! now check the code.

Comment: @ADyson just tried "$("#myModal").modal();" and its working so i will call controller from clicked event and delete it with query maybe that might work

Comment: if you are using Bootstrap already then yes that would work instead.

Comment: Make sure you check the v4 docs for eventClick though, because your function signature right now is incorrect (it's for v3!): https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick

Comment: @ADyson yup corrected it now `eventClick: function(info) {
            id = info.event.id;
            $("#myModal").modal(); }` and objective is obtained now. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson now should i delete the question or add the answer below?

Comment: You can add the answer below. Then it helps others with a similar issue, and the rest of us can vote on it (which will get you reputation points) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: first i corrected my code, i was using fullCalendar v4 libraries and i was using v3 functions which created conflict. Then i used bootsrap modal in html and called it in JS. At last i used Ajax call to delete events Code is as follows:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'bootstrap'],
        themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
         header: {
        left: false,
        center: 'title',
          },
        defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
        validRange: {
          start: '2019-08-26',
          end: '2019-09-26',
          },   
        selectable: true,
        editable  : true,
        droppable : true,
          eventClick: function(info) {
            id = info.event.id;
            $("#myModal").modal();

            window.deleteRecord=function() {
              $.ajax({
                    headers: {
                      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="edit-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "{{route('deleteRecord')}}",
                    data: JSON.stringify(id),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
              }).done( function(data){
                  console.log('Ajax was Successful!');
                  console.log(data); 
                  location.reload(true); 

              }).fail(function(data){
                  console.log('Ajax Failed');
              });
            }
          },
        eventSources: [
              {
                url: '{{"roster/getEvents"}}',
                allDay: false,
                allDayMaintainDuration: false,
                textColor: 'black',
              },
              {
                url: '{{"roster/getGazette"}}',
                editable: false,
                overlap: false,
              },
            ],
          });
        calendar.render();
        });
```